# Is it possible to setup a private TOR relay

Tags: relays, proxy, private

I have a proxy setup on one of my machines which is behind a router. And I need to use that proxy from another network.

But my problem is that I *cannot* forward ports from the router to the proxy machine. :( So I have no way to connect to the machine from outside.

To avoid this, I thought of setting up the proxy machine as a *Single hop Tor relay* instead and use *only* that node from my machine (using Tor).

But I want the relay to be private (only to be used by my machine).

Is this even possible? Or am I over-complicating this? Is there a simpler approach? (with or without Tor).

Why I am not using the standard Tor relays is that I need a stable connection 24*7 and Tor network doesn't seem to be stable always. :(

Comment: What is a stable connection in your definition?

Comment: Right now when I try connecting to the Tor network, it connects to the network, but is not able to access any site at all. It just times out.. This happens about 30% of the time. The connection is slow (but usable) at other times.

Comment: Do you want to access public websites or .onion URLs? Could it be that you're in a country with Internet censorship?

Comment: I want to access public websites. I am in Singapore and I am not able to access even google.com or whatismyip.com. I am able to access these fine without the Tor network. And I am using Orbot on a Genymotion emulator to access the network btw.

Comment: Tor offers bridges and pluggable transports. Both can give you a stable connection. just go to https://bridges.torproject.org and receive some. You enter them into Tor Browser or `torrc` and should have a working connection. If plain bridges don't work try obfs4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would think a bridge could be considered a private relay. You can even setup the bridge so it is not broadcast to the bridge authority. In that setup you would be the only person able to give out access to the bridge, so if you wanted you could keep it private to just yourself.

General info on bridges:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en

Setup obfsproxy bridge:
https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy-debian-instructions.html.en

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run a private Tor relay, where only you can use it.
If it is part of the network, other relays can use it to build circuits. (If it is not, then you can't use it either.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run a private Tor relay, but it is possible to run a hidden service with 1-hop circuits and connect to it with a Tor client running in tor2web mode. However, you need to recompile tor on both machines to change default hidden service circuit hop count (on the server) and enable tor2web mode (on the client).
Running a bridge seems inappropriate in this case, since you cannot exit directly from a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your proxy with uProxy: https://www.uproxy.org.

uProxy is free, open source, and uses WebRTC [NAT traversal techniques](https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/) to allow peers without public IPs to communicate.