# Is it possible to set up a private tor network which can connect to the Internet?

Tags: relays, directory, private

I would like a private tor network only my machines can use. These nodes are in different *physical* machines and have their own IPs. And I want to connect to public websites through private Tor network.

In this question [Is it possible to setup a private TOR relay](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-private-tor-relay) every one said it impossible to have a private tor relay.

But I wonder if I make my relays and exit nodes use my own directory server(by set `DirAuthority`), will other relays or directory server know about my relays?

I want to know if it possible...

Comment: Yes you can set up your own Tor network. [Chutney](https://github.com/torproject/chutney) is a tool that’s able to set up a *local* private Tor network. The tor source code does contain hard-coded directory authorities, but I’d recommend looking at how Chutney manages these things. For example look at the [`DirAuthority`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#DirAuthority) option of the torrc settings.

Comment: can you tell me if my relays and exit nodes use my own directory server, will others know them? thanks

Comment: No, if you set it up properly other people won’t know about it. But you should only use it for testing purposes as you won’t get the same anonymity as using the real Tor network.